# django admin error - Unknown column 'django_content_type.name' in 'field list'

Tags: python, django

My django project had a working admin page, but all of the sudden I started receiving:
 `"Unknown column 'django_content_type.name' in 'field list'"` whenever I try to access the admin page.  I can still access some portions of the admin, just not the main page.

I'm pretty new to django and python, so I have no idea where to look.

Here's the full error:

```
InternalError at /admin/
(1054, u"Unknown column 'django_content_type.name' in 'field list'")
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.7.7
Exception Type: InternalError
Exception Value:    
(1054, u"Unknown column 'django_content_type.name' in 'field list'")
Exception Location: c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py in _check_mysql_exception, line 115
Python Executable:  c:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['c:\\users\\dhysong\\Documents\\School\\CS6310\\Project4\\CS6310',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'c:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'c:\\Python27',
 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 9 Apr 2015 08:17:05 -0400
```

html error occurs on line 63:

```
In template c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\index.html, error at line 63
1054
53  <div id="content-related">
54      <div class="module" id="recent-actions-module">
55          <h2>{% trans 'Recent Actions' %}</h2>
56          <h3>{% trans 'My Actions' %}</h3>
57              {% load log %}
58              {% get_admin_log 10 as admin_log for_user user %}
59              {% if not admin_log %}
60              <p>{% trans 'None available' %}</p>
61              {% else %}
62              <ul class="actionlist">
63              {% for entry in admin_log %}
64              <li class="{% if entry.is_addition %}addlink{% endif %}{% if entry.is_change %}changelink{% endif %}{% if entry.is_deletion %}deletelink{% endif %}">
65                  {% if entry.is_deletion or not entry.get_admin_url %}
66                      {{ entry.object_repr }}
67                  {% else %}
68                      <a href="{{ entry.get_admin_url }}">{{ entry.object_repr }}</a>
69                  {% endif %}
70                  <br/>
71                  {% if entry.content_type %}
72                      <span class="mini quiet">{% filter capfirst %}{% trans entry.content_type.name %}{% endfilter %}</span>
73                  {% else %}
```

Comment: I copied the data from the user tables and removed them all and ran "migrate" again.  Whatever messed up the app was in the database because it's working again.

Comment: did you upgrade to django 1.8, and downgrade to django 1.7.7 ? You would run into this issue if you did so. The thing is `name` is no longer a model field, it was converted into a property instead..

Comment: No, I started and am still at 1.7.7.  I fixed it by deleting the django created tables and running "migrate" again.  I'm still not sure what broke.

Comment: @karthikr I did that. I was testing upgrading to 1.8 from 1.6.7. It was going to cause some issues so I decided to not go that route. Not I'm having all sorts of problems including this. And since I only did this on my dev environment I've deleted the database and resynced. It still happens... :/ Any thoughts on what could have changed?

Update: I think it may be because I upgraded my django debug toolbar and need to downgrade it back to where it was.

Update: Nope I was wrong. 1.3 is current version and should work with everything 1.4 - 1.8

Comment: @teewuane Did you check your database to see what the state is ? Does it have the column or not?

Comment: What do you mean by check the state and which table would have the column?

Comment: This exception is raised for errors which are related to MySQL's operations. For example: too many connections; a host name could not be resolved; bad handshake; server is shutting down, communication errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this same issue just now and it was related to different versions of django. I updated all of the machines working on my project to django 1.8 using pip install -U Django and everything worked fine after that.

Comment: This exception is raised for errors which are related to MySQL's operations. For example: too many connections; a host name could not be resolved; bad handshake; server is shutting down, communication errors.

Answer (score 5):

The fix in MySQL for us was to 
drop table django_content_type;

The notes from karthikr and moonchel led me to the fix. 
1054 Unknown column errors were occurring after installing 
Django 1.8 into one virtualenv to try it out, and then trying
to use the pre-existing Django 1.6 in a different virtualenv.
MySQL got messed up.

Django 1.7/1.8 syncdb revised the django_content_type table 
removing the 'name' column from it.

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| app_label | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| model     | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Django 1.6 syncdb creates the table with the 'name' column:
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name      | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| app_label | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| model     | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So drop the table and let syncdb recreate it as required for the Django version.
Take a dump if nervous about dropping it: `mysqldump -u <mysqladminname> -p <databasename> django_content_type > /tmp/django_content_type.dmp`

Comment: Cannot drop the table because it is referred in other tables.. `ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Answer (score 1):

it's not django error, it's MySQL. I just started a project, but changed django version from 1.8 to 1.7 and got this error. So, I droped all table and run migrate. But you don't need to drop all tables, just part, may be just one.

Answer (score 1):

Man I was having the same problem in a huge framework with about 45 Django apps and 12 ReactJS applications; let's go to the code that solved my case:

---

1 - first install the django packages that increase your native command options for manage.py and django in general; in addition to trying to REINSTALL by upgrading django to a new version if one is available --->

```
***"pip install -U django django-rest-framework-tricks django-shortcuts django-admin-shortcuts django_extensions";***
```

---

2 - when reading the error in detail I realized that some .pyc and **init** files were linked to the fact, so within the main project directory execute where the "manage.py" file is; we will clean, guarantee permissions and unlink all sections connected to the bank that may be disturbing the framework:

```
***"./manage.py clean_pyc", "./manage.py clear_cache", "./manage.py update_permissions", ". /manage.py clearsessions "***
```

---

3 - still within the same directory where the "manage.py" file is located if there is still a cache or temporary execution file stored, not deleted for any reason whatsoever; execute the command to force the elimination of these files that may be disturbing the framework:

```
***"sudo find. -name '* __ pycache__' -exec rm -rf {} + && \
sudo python manage.py makemigrations && \
sudo find. -path "* / migrations / *. py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete && \
sudo find. -path "* / migrations / *. pyc" -delete; "***
```

---

4 - lastly a great but excellent command to force the reindexation of models and views with the framework and the database; IN MY CASE THE APPLICATIONS I WILL MAKE TO EXAMPLE SAO (GUI_CUBE_X and BUI_CUBE_Y), PUT THE NAME OF YOUR APPLICATION; you can put HOW MANY you want, it doesn't matter, but in the two steps q is used the name has to be replicated in the 2 processes to work:

```
***"
./manage.py makemigrations && \
./manage.py migrate --fake GUI_CUBE_X zero && \
./manage.py migrate --fake GUI_CUBE_Y zero && \
./manage.py showmigrations && \
./manage.py makemigrations && \
./manage.py migrate --fake GUI_CUBE_X && \
./manage.py migrate --fake GUI_CUBE_Y && \
./manage.py makemigrations && \
./manage.py migrate && \
./manage.py collectstatic --clear --force-color --no-input;
systemctl restart uwsgi;
systemctl restart nginx;
"***
```

---

5 - test your application again

```
"./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080"
```

... and SUCCESS !!! we are ready to continue the show dude lol !!!

Enviar feedback
Histórico
Salvas
Comunidade

Answer (score 0):

Caused by two different versions of Django being installed.  I had the error when I had Django1.7 installed locally and 1.8 in a virtualenv.

```
pip uninstall django
```

for the local version, and then restarting `manage.py runserver` from within the `virtualenv` fixed the error for me.

Comment: No need to uninstall django, just activate your virtual environment and start your server using python manage.py runserver.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Django installed locally and in your virtual environment, then make sure that the virtual environment is activated.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure `django_migrations` is correct.