# django admin error - cannot access admin page

Tags: python, django, admin

I just started my new django 1.8 project. I created a superuser and went to `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` and logged in from that. After logging in, it shows the following error:

```
(1054, "Unknown column 'django_content_type.name' in 'field list'")
```

I searched around and found just one relevant question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538388/django-admin-error-unknown-column-django-content-type-name-in-field-list).

As said in the discussion there, I dropped my schema and recreated it many times; still I get the same error. The `django_content_type` table in my database has only three fields: id, app_label and model. It doesn't have 'name' which is deprecated.

Also, I can access other urls like `/admin/auth/`, `/admin/auth/users/`, but trying to add more users gives the following error(I think this is also coming due to the same problem as above):

```
Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.
```

I'm very new to Django in general. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the full error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/
(1054, "Unknown column 'django_content_type.name' in 'field list'")
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
    Django Version: 1.7.5
    Exception Type: OperationalError
    Exception Value:    
    (1054, "Unknown column 'django_content_type.name' in 'field list'")
    Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in defaulterrorhandler, line 36
    Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
    Python Version: 2.7.6
    Python Path:    
    ['/home/rahul/Development/rmgl_project',
     '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-12.1.1-py2.7.egg',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
     '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
     '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
    Server time:    Wed, 8 Jul 2015 07:19:12 +0000
```

I realised that this error shows my django version as 1.7 whereas I installed django 1.8 using `pip`. I ran `python manage.py shell` and checked my django version from there(cannot post screenshot, rep not high enough).

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 8, 2, 'final', 0)
>>>
```

How can I correct this? Thanks again. I'm using virtualenv.

Edit: adding urls.py

```
"""rmgl_project URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Add an import:  from blog import urls as blog_urls
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include(blog_urls))
"""
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Adding manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",     "rmgl_project.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: How did you set up your database? `manage.py makemigrations; manage.py migrate`?

Comment: @Evert, Yes, that way.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add your main  `urls.py` (that should contain the default admin urls)?

Comment: What is `django.__file__` btw? And what do you get when running `which python`?

Comment: `which python` gives
`/home/rahul/.virtualenvs/rmgl_project/bin/python`


`django.__file__` is

`'/home/rahul/.virtualenvs/rmgl_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.pyc'`

Comment: Please, show `./manage.py` file and the way you are starting the server.

Comment: @soon, I start server by `./manage.py runserver`

Comment: Can't figure the problem now, but will running `python manage.py runserver` instead of `./manage.py runserver` solve the problem? If no, could you, please, add a `print(__import__('django'))` to `./manage.py` in order to show the path to the module, and paste the output of `./manage runserver` here?

Comment: @soon that is likely: it looks like `manage.py` was probably copied and contains the wrong path to Python: there is no sign of the virtualenv in the error message's PYTHONPATH. @RahulYadav check the first line of `manage.py`: it probably contains a path pointing outside your virtualenv.

Comment: I don't suppose using `python manage.py runserver` should cause any change. I tried and nothing out of ordinary happened. I ran `./manage.py runserver` after adding that line. The result is as follows,

`Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)`
`[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2`
`Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`
`(InteractiveConsole)`
`>>>`

It printed nothing special.

Comment: @Evert, However, I have the same `manage.py`, but it runs correct Python version, even with virtual environments.

Comment: @Evert, what I posted in the question is the complete `manage.py` file.

Comment: @soon, sorry, the correct result of that line is 
`Django version 1.7.5, using settings 'rmgl_project.settings'`

Comment: @RahulYadav, That is strange, since it should print something like this: `<module 'django' from '/home/soon/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py'>`

Comment: Does this mean there's something wrong with my `settings.py` file?

Comment: No, this means that there is something wrong with `virtualenv` settings. Please, replace `print` line with `print(__import__('django').__file__)` and show the output again.

Comment: This time it shows `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.pyc`. Moreover, this same line is printed twice.

Comment: Sounds strange, but have you [activated](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) your `virtualenv`? Try to deactivate and activate it again.

Comment: Oh my gosh! I'm so stupid. I wasn't running my server from inside the `virtualenv`. Thank you for being so patient with me, @soon, @Evert. As soon as I ran from the inside, everything works fine. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with virtualenv - it was not enabled.

In order to check the version of Django (and the path to the module), you could add the following lines to `./manage.py` file:

```
print(__import__('django')) # Should print the module information
print(__import__('django').__file__) # Should print the location of __init__.py file
```

Right after the `if __name__ == '__main__'` line.