# Django 1.7/1.10: 1054, "Unknown column 'django_content_type.name' in 'field list'"

Tags: mysql, django-admin, django-contenttypes

After accidentally running the server using Django 1.10 and possibly run a syncdb/migrate I am getting the following message when I try to access the admin

```
OperationalError at /admin/

(1054, "Unknown column 'django_content_type.name' in 'field list'")

Request Method:     GET 
Request URL:    http://xx.com:8000/admin/ 
Django Version:     1.7 
Exception Type:     OperationalError Exception Value:   

(1054, "Unknown column 'django_content_type.name' in 'field list'")

Exception Location:     build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py in defaulterrorhandler, line 36 
Python Executable:  /tools/python/2.7.3/linux64/bin/python 
Python Version:     2.7.3
```

this seems to be the same issue as the one below:

[django admin error - Unknown column 'django_content_type.name' in 'field list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538388/django-admin-error-unknown-column-django-content-type-name-in-field-list)

However when I look at the Django_content_type table I do not see a "name" column.

```
mysql> show columns from django_content_type;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| app_label | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| model     | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried to drop the table but got the following message:

```
mysql> drop table if exists django_content_type ;
ERROR 1217 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I am fairly new to Django and MYSQL and I am at a loss here as to what to do next.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Eric.

Comment: I have resolved this issue but not found the root cause. The Django_content_type table above is incorrect for Django 1.7 (I believe) and missing a name column (removed in 1.8 I think but I am not sure).

I believe the root cause was a makemigrations/migrate I ran using django 1.10 by error but looking at the migrations files I can not tell and There is no indication (that I found) which Django version is used to generate a migration. That would be a good enhancement.